# How to toggle Bootstrap 3 classes?

Tags: javascript

I have this halfway working and have two columns. One column holds photo listings col-md-8 and the other shows a map col-md-4. My goal is to toggle the map and show the listings column taking up all 12 columns. Right now I have only figured out how to hide the map and expand the listings column but now it needs to show back. I also need to switch the button text show/hide based on toggled state. Any help appreciated.

Here is what I figured out so far.

```
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#map').hide();
 $('.expand-column').removeClass('col-md-8');
 $('.expand-column').addClass('col-md-12');
    });
```

Comment: Isn't the *"needs to show back"* just the opposite of what you have already? Where are you stuck with doing that? Seems like you just need to keep working at this. SO isn't a free code writing service

Comment: I think I need a condition of some sort.

Comment: Well you could toggle a class on a parent container of these columns , or even on the button and check for that class so you know the current state and do what is applicable based on going to the opposite

Comment: Post the HTML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the current methods with toggle methods and make what you currently have work both ways

```
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#map').toggle();
     $('.expand-column').toggleClass('col-md-8 col-md-12'); 
});
```

I'll leave it to you to come up with a variable or another class to keep track of the current state with and use that to determine the text

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was so close. Have a Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

After implementing charlietfl answer, here is what I came up with for handling the current state of the toggling text.

```
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if($(this).text()=="hide map") {
    $(this).text("show map");
 } else {
    $(this).text("hide map");
 }
 $('#map').toggle();
 $('.expand-column').toggleClass('col-md-8 col-md-12'); 
 $('.constrain-photos').toggleClass('col-lg-3 col-lg-2');
 return false;
});
```